# Solving multiple linear systems using vectorization

Tags: matlab, linear-algebra

Sorry if this is obvious but I searched a while and did not find anything (or missed it).

I'm trying to solve linear systems of the form *Ax=B* with *A* a 4x4 matrix, and *B* a 4x1 vector.

I know that for a single system I can use `mldivide` to obtain *x*: `x=A\B`.

However I am trying to solve a great number of systems (possibly > 10000) and I am reluctant to use a for loop because I was told it is notably slower than matrix formulation in many MATLAB problems.

My question is then: is there a way to solve *Ax=B* using vectorization with *A* 4x4x *N* and *B* a matrix 4x *N* ?

PS: I do not know if it is important but the *B* vector is the same for all the systems.

Comment: The whole concept of performance boosts in MATLAB by using matrices is called [vectorization](http://www.mathworks.com/support/tech-notes/1100/1109.html) and isn't as simple as "if it's in matrix form -> it's *always* faster" as you can see from the answers.

Comment: @Jacob: yes I meant vectorization, thank you for editing. I know that sometimes you cannot avoid loops but it's just that from the way I learned Matlab and given all the native functions that are oriented in a way to favor vectorization, I wondered if the experiencted people of this site had already been confronted to this problem. Thanks to @Tom and @Amro for their answers and to @Rasman and @eat for their alternatives.

Comment: I have a feeling that this is a common scenario to run into (and something that the Matlab developers could improve). I'm running a similar for loop millions of times.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use a for loop. There might be a benefit in precomputing a factorization and reusing it, if `A` stays the same and `B` changes. But for your problem where `A` changes and `B` stays the same, there's no alternative to solving N linear systems.

You shouldn't worry too much about the performance cost of loops either: the [MATLAB JIT compiler](http://www.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/news_notes/may03/profiler.html) means that loops can often be just as fast on recent versions of MATLAB.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think you can optimize this further. As explained by @Tom, since `A` is the one changing, there is no benefit in factoring the various `A`'s beforehand...

Besides the looped solution is pretty fast given the dimensions you mention:

```
A = rand(4,4,10000);
B = rand(4,1);          %# same for all linear systems

tic
X = zeros(4,size(A,3));
for i=1:size(A,3)
    X(:,i) = A(:,:,i)\B;
end
toc
```

> Elapsed time is 0.168101 seconds.

Comment: 0.091238 seconds... much faster then I expected :). Good point on the small dimension of A as it reduces significantly the complexity of the problem

Answer (score 3):

Here's the problem:
you're trying to perform a 2D operation ([mldivide](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/mldivide.html)) on a 3d matrix. No matter how you look at it, you need reference the matrix by index which is where the time penalty kicks in... it's not the for loop which is the problem, but it's how people use them.
If you can structure your problem differently, then perhaps you can find a better option, but right now you have a few options:

1 - mex

2 - parallel processing (write a parfor loop)

3 - CUDA

Comment: @Jacob: No, `parfor` will actually be slower here. From Amro's timing (and Rasman's in the comment), the avg time taken per task is ~10<sup>-6</sup> seconds. The time taken by the scheduler to communicate with the workers is slower than that or maybe of the same order of magnitude. So factoring that in, it will be slower. On my machine it takes ~0.1 seconds total w/o `parfor` and ~0.5 seconds total w/ `parfor` and 8 workers.

Comment: @yoda if the division was the only operation, then you're right, but otherwise, it may or may not be be useful

Comment: @yoda and @Jacob: the difference is small, but take away the time for opening the pools and my parfor runs through the system a bit faster then then the for loop  (the difference becomes more apparent when you increase the number of iterations e.g. 100000)

Comment: @yoda: parfor overhead is heavily dependent on the processor. The newer Intel multicores have noticeably lower communication overhead.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a rather esoteric solution that takes advantage of MATLAB's peculiar optimizations. Construct an enormous 4k x 4k *sparse* matrix with your 4x4 blocks down the diagonal. Then solve all simultaneously.

On my machine this gets the same solution up to single precision accuracy as @Amro/Tom's for-loop solution, but faster.

```
n = size(A,1);
k = size(A,3);
AS = reshape(permute(A,[1 3 2]),n*k,n);
S = sparse( ...
  repmat(1:n*k,n,1)', ...
  bsxfun(@plus,reshape(repmat(1:n:n*k,n,1),[],1),0:n-1), ...
  AS, ...
  n*k,n*k);
X = reshape(S\repmat(B,k,1),n,k);
```

for a random example:

```
For k = 10000
For loop: 0.122570 seconds.
Giant sparse system: 0.032287 seconds.
```

If you know that your 4x4 matrices are positive definite then you can use `chol` on S to improve the accuracy.

This is *silly*. But so is how slow matlab's for loops *still* are in 2015, even with JIT. This solution seems to find a sweet spot when k is not too large so everything still fits into memory.

Comment: I'm curious - would the same strategy work if the size of `B` was changed from `B = rand(4,1)` to `B = rand(4,4)`? For `Nx=32`, my test data references `A = rand(Nx+1,Nx+1,Nx); % size (33,33,32)` and 
`B = rand(Nx+1,Nx) % size (33,32)`. The line `X = reshape(S\repmat(B,k,1),n,k);` no longer works since `S\repmat(B,k,1)` is of size 1056 by 32 instead of 1056 by 1.

Comment: It should work if you put the columns of B in the columns of the rhs of the solve.

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean by the RHS of the solve?

Comment: I don't think I understand the dimensions of your matrices. In the original post, A was 4x4xN so that A(:,:,1) is a 4x4 matrix. B is a 4xN, so that B(:,1) is 4x1. This way A(:,:,1) \ B(:,1) makes sense. If you're saying that B should now be 4x4xN so that B(:,:,1) is 4x4 and A(:,:,1) \ B(:,:,1) continues to make sense. Then analogous solution is to sprinkle the As along the diagonal of S and reshape the Bs into a vertical stack so that you can do Xs = As \ Bs  and Xs will be a 4*N x 4 stack of solutions.

Answer (score 2):

I know this post is years old now, but I'll contribute my two cents anyway.  You CAN put all of your A matricies into a bigger block diagonal matrix, where there will be 4x4 blocks on the diagonal of a big matrix.  The right hand side will be all of your b vectors stacked on top of each other over and over.  Once you set this up, it is represented as a sparse system, and can be efficiently solved with the algorithms mldivide chooses.  The blocks are numerically decoupled, so even if there are singular blocks in there, the answers for the nonsingular blocks should be right when you use mldivide.  There is a code that took this approach on MATLAB Central:

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/24260-multiple-same-size-linear-solver

I suggest experimenting to see if the approach is any faster than looping.  I suspect it can be more efficient, especially for large numbers of small systems.  In particular, if there are nice formulas for the coefficients of A across the N matricies, you can build the full left hand side using MATLAB vector operations (without looping), which could give you additional cost savings.  As others have noted, vectorized operations aren't always faster, but they often are in my experience.