# Is it possible to use mldivide "\" on a 3D matrix in Matlab

Tags: matlab, vectorization

Is it possible to use `mldivide` (`\`) on a 3D matrix in MATLAB? I would like to avoid using a for loop?

Sample:

```
A = rand(4, 100, 5);
B = rand(4,4);
```

I need to perform:

```
C = B\A;
```

What I'm doing now:

Apply the mldivide on a for loop for each "slice" i:

```
for i = 1:size(A, 3)    
    C(:,:,i) = B \ A(:,:,i); 
end
```

Comment: Does `A (4,100,5)` imply that `size(A)=[4 100 5]`?

Comment: Sorry, yes. Going to edit.

Comment: Also, seems relevant - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6344800/solving-multiple-linear-systems-using-vectorization

Comment: The size is just a sample.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can reshape `A` into a 2D matrix to perform the division and then back to the expected size afterwards. The `reshape` operations should be relatively quick due to the fact that MATLAB doesn't alter the underlying data.

```
C = reshape(B \ reshape(A, size(A, 1), []), size(B, 1), size(A, 2), []);
```

And if we break that down:

```
%// Reshape A to be 4 x 500
Anew = reshape(A, size(A, 1), []);

%// Perform left division
C = B \ Anew;

%// Reshape C to be the expected size (4 x 100 x 5)
C = reshape(C, size(B, 1), size(A, 2), []);
```

This should work for any valid (`size(A, 1) == size(B, 2)`) matrices `A` and `B` of any size.